# Extjs tooltip on overflow button

Tags: button, text, tooltip, overflow, extjs4.1

I am trying to add a tooltip on extjs overflow button, but I can't find a way to do that. It's not mentioned on docs either. Has anyone been able to do that? Either that or changing the text for the button

[image]

I found

```
overflowText: 'More >'
```

But this doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a tooltip to the overflow button during the `afterrender` event of the toolbar. The target element would be `this.layout.overflowHandler.menuTrigger.el` in the `afterrender` event.

**Working jsFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/gJjTY/ (the overflow icon is in the bottom right of the toolbar, the icon isn't rendering due to lack of css)

```
Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
    renderTo: document.body,
    width   : 300,
    margin  : '5 0 0 0',
    layout  : {overflowHandler: 'Menu' },
    items   : [
        {
            text   : 'This is a Button',
            tooltip: 'This is a tip',
        },
        {
            text   : 'This is another button',
        },
        {
            text : "this is yet another button!"
        }
    ],
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(view){
            var me = this;
            console.log(me);
            Ext.Function.defer(function(){
                Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
                    target       : me.layout.overflowHandler.menuTrigger.el,
                    anchor       : 'left',
                    dismissDelay : 0,
                    showDelay    : 0,
                    autoHide     : true,
                    html         : "This is a tooltip!"
                });
            }, 100);
        }
    }
});

Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.QuickTips.interceptTitles = true;
    Ext.QuickTips.init();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much John Hall. This is exactly what I am trying to do. Sweeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeet :)

Comment: Do you know how to add a tooltip to the overflow menu items? All my toolbar items have a tooltip until they enter the overflow menu and then the tooltip does not work. @John Hall

Comment: @joe You can likely modify one of the Component's *tplAttr properties to include "data-qtip={tip}" and as long as you initialize QuickTips and provide the Component with the proper Data (i.e., to feed the Template), it should "just work"

Comment: @JohnHall I was talking to some other users on here and it may also be a Sencha bug. They recommended moving to type: 'Scroller'